# Run .NET Core on Linux - writing nothing

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono, coreclr

I created project vNext Console Application in Visual Studio. I copied these files to linux machine. And try to run them

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-Virtual-Machine:~/ConsoleApp2/src/ConsoleApp2$ dnvm list

Active Version              Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------              ------- ------------ --------------- -----
  *    1.0.0-rc1-final      coreclr x64          linux           
       1.0.0-rc1-final      mono                 linux/osx       default

ubuntu@ubuntu-Virtual-Machine:~/ConsoleApp2/src/ConsoleApp2$ dnu restore
ubuntu@ubuntu-Virtual-Machine:~/ConsoleApp2/src/ConsoleApp2$ dnx run
ubuntu@ubuntu-Virtual-Machine:~/ConsoleApp2/src/ConsoleApp2$
```

My application is not running. However if I switch dnvm to mono it works ok.
Content of my files is

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Program
    {
        public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world!!!!");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

**project.json**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "ConsoleApp2 Console Application",
  "authors": [ "Anton" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "dependencies": {

  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {},
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {

        "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23019"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Why does dnx command write nothing when switched to coreclr?

Comment: Hmm. It works okay for me... very odd.

Comment: @JonSkeet do you run your app under dnxcore or dnx451. If use I use mono it's all ok. But dnx in coreclr still write nothing for me

Comment: I was using coreclr, just like the configuration you showed.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly sure you're missing one of the prerequisites. They are listed [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-linux.html):

```
sudo apt-get install libunwind8 gettext libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev zlib1g libicu-dev uuid-dev
```